# Create custom field by subtracting column values from two different rows based on multiple IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to create custom column by subtracting column values from two different rows based on multiple IDs.

Data set is like below:

```
------------------------------------------
Date       | Name | ID1  | ID2  | Value
------------------------------------------
2020-03-01 | ABC  | 50   | 75   | 2000
2020-03-02 | ABC  | 50   | 75   | 3000
2020-03-03 | ABC  | 50   | 75   | 3140
2020-03-01 | ABC  | 50   | 76   | 5000
2020-03-02 | ABC  | 50   | 76   | 6000
2020-03-03 | ABC  | 50   | 76   | 6145
2020-03-01 | ABC  | 50   | 77   | 5000
2020-03-02 | ABC  | 50   | 77   | 6000
2020-03-03 | ABC  | 50   | 77   | 6145
```

ID2 is different for each date. Now I have to display custom field like below:

```
---------------------------------------------------
Date       | Name | ID1  | ID2  | Value |  Custom 
--------------------------------------------------
2020-03-01 | ABC  | 50   | 75   | 2000  | 1000 (3000-2000)
2020-03-02 | ABC  | 50   | 75   | 3000  | 140  (3140 -3000)
2020-03-03 | ABC  | 50   | 75   | 3140  | Next date Value - 3140 
...

...
```

Repeated for other ID2 also.

Please suggest how should I proceed. I tried using `Cross Join` but but not giving desirable result.

Comment: Please include the actual value for `Next date Value - 3140` ... we can't infer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Date] DATE
   ,[Name] CHAR(3)
   ,[ID1] TINYINT
   ,[ID2] TINYINT
   ,[Value] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Date], [Name], [ID1], [ID2], [Value])
VALUES ('2020-03-01', 'ABC ', '50', '75', '2000')
      ,('2020-03-02', 'ABC ', '50', '75', '3000')
      ,('2020-03-03', 'ABC ', '50', '75', '3140')
      ,('2020-03-01', 'ABC ', '50', '76', '5000')
      ,('2020-03-02', 'ABC ', '50', '76', '6000')
      ,('2020-03-03', 'ABC ', '50', '76', '6145')
      ,('2020-03-01', 'ABC ', '50', '77', '5000')
      ,('2020-03-02', 'ABC ', '50', '77', '6000')
      ,('2020-03-03', 'ABC ', '50', '77', '6145');

SELECT *
     ,LEAD([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [ID1], [ID2] ORDER BY [Date] ASC)
     ,CONCAT(LEAD([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [ID1], [ID2] ORDER BY [Date] ASC) - [value], ' (', LEAD([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [ID1], [ID2] ORDER BY [Date] ASC), ' -', [value],')')
FROM @DataSource
ORDER BY [Date]
```

You can add more logic in the final `CONCAT` in order to shape the results in different way. For example, if there is not `next value` to be get, you can leave the value `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       (value - lead(value, 1, 0) over (partition by id1, id2 order by date)) as diff
from t;
```

Comment: Both the answers are correct. Thanks a ton for help.